# Do we have a selectbox widget for gmail add-ons?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

Right now I use radio buttons instead of selectbox. But I prefer selectboxes. Do we have one for gmail add-ons ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  There are three different types. Checkbox, Radio Button and DropDown. Read [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/selection-input-type). I find the switch to be useful as well.

Comment: Got it. Thanks coop.